# One large table or break them down? (Optimal database)

Tags: database, database-design

I've looked around trying to figure out the best way to handle my database, and I have some questions.

Is it better to have a large table or separate tables? Is there any real difference as far as server load?

I paid a guy to put together a database and some php so I could break into it, and he made 2 separate tables for what, I think, should be one. Seems to be redundant, and I no likey repeating myself.

Basically, `x_content` is:

```
ID | section | page | heading | content
```

and `x_menu` is

```
ID | PARENT | LINK | DISPLAY | HASCHILD
```

(personally, it bugs me about the caps. I think I'll go Standard Case since everything else on the site is all-lowercase or in script camelCase)

Anyway, ID, (heading/DISPLAY), and (page/LINK) are more/less (can be) the same. Seems to me I'd be doing myself a favor by combining these, and adding the rest of what I want.

What I'd Like:

```
ID | Category | Name | URL | Description | Keywords | Content | Theme
```

So- should I delete the `x_menu` and combine them?

*If I link all of the pages in my site right now, it would be something like 40+

Answer (score 0):

If menu is build dynamically in your application, I would suggest to have a separate table for menu for easy maintenance.

However, in your combined table, I don't see any "menu" column. I don't know whether you'd like to replace it with URL. But difference I find is every page has url but it may or may not be included in menu.

If "menu" is not build dynamically, I think more information must be provided to consider whether menu needs to be separate entity.

Comment: He did have a dynamic menu. I was thinking about re-using it. After all, the menu table is done already. So keep the menu table and add the rest to x_content?

Comment: I am sorry if I am wrong in understanding your question. In your post you said, you will delete x_menu table and combine x_menu and x_content. If this is case, it will be maintenance problem, it is better to maintain menu items in a separate table which you already doing. And all your additional columns such as "content",  "keywords", "theme" ,etc go into "x_content" table since every page has these attributes.

Comment: Right, I'm going to keep both of them and build on x_content. Thanks for the help!